# How to access first UIViewController again from another UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have developed a view-based application and I am facing a problem with heading back to the first view of my application from another view.

If I put my problem in a pictorial way, I think it will be clear.

```
 Welcome Page   ----> Login Page  ----->  Login Success page with log out button
```

I have the welcome page which will be shown to the user when he/she run the application and user will be directed to login page which will check user's credentials and then user will be directed to Login Success page.

In the Login Success page, there is a logout button and when user clicks on that he/she should be come back to **Welcome page**.

I have used `presentModalViewController` in order to move from one view to another. I was trying to use the same approach in Login success page's logout button, but that gives an error when running the application.

Can any one help me out to sort out this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please post some code and more information about your error. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should have the main UIViewController, which presented the second one call `dismissModalViewController:animated:`.

Comment: or within your login view controller call `[self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]´. @mmmrbm: if you want navigation between pages, use a UINavigationController with it's pushViewController/popViewController functions. modal presentaitons are used to present **1** ViewController for a short amount of time (perfect for login screens that go away quickly, but not to use for normal transitions between viewcontrollers)

Comment: Hi Moshe and Martin,

Sorry for this much of delay as I got some health issues. And buddies, thanks in millions for taking interest to answer my question.

Using dismissModalViewController:animated: from Login Success page will make me go back to Login Page, but not to Welcome Page. I need to get back to Welcome Page from Login Success page.

Thing is I have already done the application as view-based application. If there is no other way I will try to re-do the application using a navigation-based project.

Thanks again to both of you in big time, for your inputs and time.